# Show all items via a foreach of a Linq expression

Tags: c#, database, linq, lambda

I’m trying to make a price list, quantity, product name but I can’t show these items that someone knows what I’m doing wrong?
Thank you.

```
float precototal = 0
                var ClienteCompraQuantidade =
                    from c in basedados.DetalheCompra
                    where c.ComprasNrCompra == p.NrCompra
                    select c.Quantidade;

                var ClienteCompraPreco =
                    from c in basedados.DetalheCompra
                    join f in basedados.Produto
                         on c.ProdutosCodProduto equals f.CodProduto
                    where c.ComprasNrCompra == p.NrCompra && c.ProdutosCodProduto == f.CodProduto
                    select f.Designacao;

                var ClienteCompraDesignacao=
                    from c in basedados.DetalheCompra
                    join f in basedados.Produto
                         on c.ProdutosCodProduto equals f.CodProduto
                    where c.ComprasNrCompra == p.NrCompra && c.ProdutosCodProduto == f.CodProduto
                    select f.Preco;

                StreamWriter ficheiro = new StreamWriter(@"C:Recibo.txt", false, Encoding.Default);
                ficheiro.WriteLine("Itens comprados:");
                foreach (var i in ClienteCompraQuantidade)
                {
                    int preco = Convert.ToInt32(ClienteCompraPreco) * Convert.ToInt32(ClienteCompraQuantidade);

                    precototal = precototal + preco;

                    ficheiro.WriteLine("" +ClienteCompraQuantidade. + "|" + ClienteCompraDesignacao. + "     |" + preco);
                }
```

Comment: ....don't you want `i` there?

Comment: I would prefer without it because I have another case I have 3 item

Comment: but... accessing the iterator is the _whole point_ of using a `foreach` loop. that is 100% what this loop is made for. executing an action _for each_ element of a collection. can you please be _a lot_ more specific about what you're trying to achieve, and what your trouble is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently writing out the *LIST* (object) of participants, not each individual participant. You should:

```
 ficheiro.WriteLine(i);
```

In your `foreach`

EDIT:

So your question now is very different from what it was originally... However, you are still making the same mistake. In your `foreach` you try to do things like this:

```
Convert.ToInt32(ClienteCompraPreco)
```

Note that `ClienteCompraPreco` is *NOT* a number. I believe you think you're getting a number out of your LINQ query above, but your are not. You are getting a `List` of `Designacao`s (`List<Designacao>` -- maybe each `Designacao` is an `int`). You can't convert a `List` to a number. Imagine that the list is `[1, 2, 3]`; what number should that be converted to?

You need to either get a single value out each of your queries (by doing, for example, `.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Designacao)` instead of `.Select(f.Designacao)`), or you need to deal with the fact that the results are `List`s in the `foreach`.

Comment: Hello thanks, I updated my question can you help me now?